# Python: Integrating a Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, integration

I have plotted a graph using matplotlib.pyplot. I need to integrate specific sections of this graph. All the tutorials I can find online are including drawing a graph from scratch, but what should I use if I already have a graph and just want to integrate a part of it?

Thank you!

Comment: You have plotted the graph, so you have the data. Then you can integrate using that data. That has actually nothing to do with Matplotlib.

Comment: For example, you might be able to use [`numpy.trapz`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html). There may be other options, but that really depends on what your data is; perhaps it is a simple y = f(x) function, in which case there are likely better options to calculate the integral.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, @9769953, numpy.trapz worked perfectly.